# Is it possible to add Swift sources to Xcode? If yes, how?

Tags: swift

Now that Swift is open source and that they released some libraries' sources like `Foundation`, I was wondering how I could add those into `Xcode` so that I can for example have a look into `NSString` (even `String`?) for any project I would create without adding sources as libraries every time.

A way to have access to the `.swift` file and not the public `".h"` version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The open-source release of Swift includes Foundation and other [core libraries](https://swift.org/source-code/#core-libraries)... ***but these are not the same libraries*** that you get when developing for Apple platforms with Xcode and its included SDKs.

On iOS (and other Apple platforms), Foundation is built in Objective-C. When you develop in Swift using Xcode SDKs, the Swift runtime automatically bridges calls to/from ObjC code. Apple does not publish the source code for this version of Foundation.

When you build with open-source Swift for non-Apple platforms (e.g. Linux), you get the [open-source, entirely-Swift version of Foundation](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation) instead. This is an completely separate project, which aims to provide Swift *equivalents* of most of the key primitive and utility class from the original Foundation. (And it's currently [incomplete](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Docs/Status.md).)

The idea here is that one should be able to write Swift code that makes use of `NSURL`, `NSDate`, `NSFileManager`, `NSFormatter`, `NSString` (i.e. the set of rich, internationalized string handling features beyond the basics that `Swift.String` provides), et cetera, and have it work regardless of whether that code gets built with Xcode for Apple platforms or with open-source Swift for other platforms. So the APIs are the same, but the implementations are different.

However, both implementations of Foundation rely on lower-level libraries that are open source. The most basic parts of Foundation are provided by [CoreFoundation](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/) — a C library that's been part of Apple's Darwin open source releases for many years. Other parts use the [International Components for Unicode](http://site.icu-project.org) library, `libdispatch`, and `libxml2`.

---

Anyhow... when you're working in a Swift project in Xcode, the [Jump to Definition](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/chapters/OpeningtheHeaderFileThatDefinesaSymbol.html) (Cmd-click) feature should get you to the Swift interfaces for ObjC classes in the SDK, not the ObjC headers for those classes. There isn't a handy way to make Xcode look up the actual source code for those classes (where they happen to be open source), but you can follow the links above.

Comment: Okay, I had it mixed up in my mind. Too bad... Thanks anyway